# Logs are written to server logs instead of application log

Tags: logging, log4j, jetty, slf4j

In my java web-app running over Jetty, at some point the logs started to be written to the server (Jetty) logs instead of the application log. I would expect to see my logs written to logs/appLog.log but for some reason I only see them written to the default log of Jetty. What can cause that? How can I fix it?

Here is my log4j.xml file:

```
<appender name="fileAppenderInfo" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="file" value="logs/appLog.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="30" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppenderErrors" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="file" value="logs/error/errorLog.log" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="30" />
    <param name="threshold" value="ERROR" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.amazonaws">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>


<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderInfo" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderErrors" />
</root>
```

Here are my logger maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have slf4j and log4j setup on the server side too?  Or just in the application?

Comment: Actually I don't know, what should I do to check the server side?